# rxjs observable debounceTime inner next ignored

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

It seems that `debounceTime` ignores inner calls to it's subjects `next` method:

```
var subject: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

subject.pipe(
    tap((a) => console.log("tab:" + a)), 
    debounceTime(300), 
).subscribe((a) => {
    console.log(a);
    subject.next(100)
});

subject.next(19);
subject.next(20);
```

the code above should create an infinite loop - but it does not:

```
tab:19
tab:20
20
tab:100
```

if I add a `delay(1)` to the pipe it works as expected:

```
subject.pipe(
    tap((a) => console.log("tab:" + a)), 
    debounceTime(300), 
    delay(1)
).subscribe((a) => {
    console.log(a);
    subject.next(100)
});
```

am I missing something?

**Edit**: added an example: https://typescript-fbt2mn.stackblitz.io

Comment: This usage looks like an edge-case to me, I never had to do something similar. It looks RxJS "resets" the debounce time after it notified the Observers, which is a synchronous operation since an older version of RxJS. Let me reverse the question, what behavior are you trying to achieve and do you have any problems with your workaround?

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3218

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of issues where something seems to be broken and that can be magically fixed with using `delay(0)` or `setTimeout` usually means that you're expecting RxJS to behave asynchronously all the time while in fact it usually works synchronously unless forced to do otherwise.

And that's exactly your case.

- When debounce pushes its value you're on this line https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.10/src/operators/debounceTime.ts#L100.
- Inside `subscribe` you call `next` which reaches `_next` inside `debounceTime` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.10/src/operators/debounceTime.ts#L84 which sets `lastValue` and `hasValue` internal variables.
- Now it starts going upwards in the call stack and only now it stops processing this line https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.10/src/operators/debounceTime.ts#L100. At this point it continues and overrides `lastValue` and `hasValue` again https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.10/src/operators/debounceTime.ts#L101-L102. This sets them to `null` and `false`.
- Then after `300ms` `debounceTime` wants to emit its value but `hasValue` is `null` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.10/src/operators/debounceTime.ts#L99 because it was already overrided.

Btw, a little more elegant way is using the `observeOn` operator with an `async` scheduler that should be more performance efficient then `delay(1)`.

```
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';

var obs = Observable.of(1, 2, 3);
var subject: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

subject.pipe(
    tap((a) => console.log("tab:" + a)), 
    debounceTime(300),
    observeOn(async),
).subscribe((a) => {
    console.log(a);
    subject.next(a+1)
});
```

See you updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tsek9s?file=index.ts

Edit: This behavior has probably changed in RxJS 6: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3218

Comment: epic! thank you so much for the explanation - totally expected async behavior :)

Comment: This is indeed a seriously epic explanation (comment will self destruct). Nicely done.